# In propositional logic, if $\Gamma \vdash \bot$, does it mean I can't derive anything else from it?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

What I've been told is that an inconsistent set of propositions is irrelevant in propositional logic because if it derives a contradiction, then you can't derive anything else from it, but here's my doubt:

Take $\Gamma = \{p \land q, \neg(p \land q)\}.$ This clearly derives a contradiction. But by $(\land E)$, can't I derive both p and q from $p \land q$, such that I can say that $\Gamma \vdash p$ and $\Gamma \vdash q$?

Comment: From a contradiction, you can derive everything, not nothing. Who told you you couldn't derive anything? You just can't derive anything **useful,** because you can derive both $p$ and $\lnot p.$

Comment: From $\bot$ we can derive a formula whatever, provided that [Ex Falso rule](https://iep.utm.edu/natural-deduction/#H4) : $\bot \vdash \varphi$ is part of the system.

Comment: And yes, from $p \land q$ you can derive both $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Essentially, we want "derivation" to mean truth, but if you can derive a contradiction, then everything is both true and false, which is not a useful logical system.